# Giving the content inside td tag a margin

Tags: jquery

I am trying to give the content inside the tag  a margin using

```
$('td *').css("margin-right","100");
```

with no success http://jsfiddle.net/R3UDU/7/

Why is this not working?.

Comment: Because there is no element inside the TD tag to apply a margin to.  You only have textual content.  Maybe you'd want to apply padding to the TD cell instead?  Otherwise, wrap your text content in a div or span.

Comment: What @JohnStrickler said and also give your value a unit, e.g. `"100px"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is padding-right ok to?

http://jsfiddle.net/R3UDU/8/

```
$('td').css("padding-right","100px");
```

and yes remove the "*" and also add px to the style

Answer (score 1):

Two things wrong:

1. There aren't any elements inside your TD.
2. You haven't specified the unit for your margin.

I've created an example for you using a span inside the TD and setting your right margin to 100px:  http://jsfiddle.net/R3UDU/9/.

Of course, this could get crazy ridiculous if you have several elements inside your TD.  If you only want to target the direct children of the TD regardless of element type, try:

```
$('td > *').css('margin-right', '100px');
```

But then, if that's what you want, why not just use padding?

```
$('td').css('padding-right', '100px');
```

Or even better, just use CSS:

```
td {padding-right: 100px;}
```

Or:

```
td > * {margin-right: 100px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `td`'s only have text nodes, you can't apply that css to text nodes -

You can do this -

```
$('td').contents().wrap($('<span/>').css("margin-right", "100px"));
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/R3UDU/10/

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to put space to the right of the text?  If so, what you want is 'padding', not 'margin'.

Try:

```
td{border:1px solid green;padding-right:100px;}
```